# SonarQube analysis mode: preview vs issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Which are the key differences between these **preview** and **issues** modes of SonarQube (greater than 5.2) analysis?

Considering http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Concepts the main differences between **publish** and **preview** is that **preview** reports only issues (no measures) and no report is pushed back to the SonarQube server; this idea is clear. But what about **issues**? It is written that **issues** is the same as **preview**, but should be used only for tools development. I'm a little confused, what do they mean by tools?

Answer (score 8):

The theory is that preview mode is what a end user should use for example when using issues report feature. The goal is to run an analysis without publishing results. The issues mode is a technical mode similar to preview but focusing only on issues. It can be used in combination with one of the pull request analysis plugin (like GitHub plugin).

Now in practice, in SonarQube 5.6, they are doing exactly the same thing. It is a bit confusing I admit, so maybe we could try to simplify this.

Comment: what if I need the incremental mode and the report still need to be published to the SonarQube server? Is there any mode for this?

Comment: @TungTran in my case I am running Sonar with Jenkins. In the end, I have solved this with two tasks: one for PRs where Sonar sends a report to Bitbucket (issues). The second for the PR merges, where Sonar runs a second time and the report is saved in the web dashboard (preview)

Answer (score 5):

sonar.analysis.mode Deprecated since SQ 6.6. see https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/

Comment: Not present anymore in that link. A working link is https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/analysis/analysis-parameters/

Comment: The parameter seems to have been removed completely in 8.5.