# Disable SonarQube plugin for specific projects

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Cut to the chase : I think I need to **disable SonarQube Github Plugin** from the sonarqube server for **specific projects** if I want to do both of the following :

**Publish to sonarqube server** & **report to github using github plugin.**
It is my understanding that installing [SonarQube Github Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) on a SonarQube server forbids the whole server from storing any analysis, forever. Therefore, I need to find a way to stop using the github plugin for only specific projects. Is there a way to do that?

P.S. Backstory
My original question was [Can't publish results to Sonarqube server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754033/cant-publish-results-to-sonarqube-server)).
However, Upon finding [Why does SonarQube not show results, although the analysis succeeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781158/why-does-sonarqube-not-show-results-although-the-analysis-succeeded), user "Wirone" says that it doesn't show results in sonar server because Sonarqube Github plugin forces `sonar.analysis.mode` to be set as `preview` or `issues`, but not `publish`.
**According to Wirone, sonarscanner doesn't send result to the server unless the mode is set as `publish`.**
I've tried to find out the exact meaning of `sonar.analysis.mode`, but articles https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/JguVVO4OorE or [SonarQube analysis mode: preview vs issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118631/sonarqube-analysis-mode-preview-vs-issues) were not helpful at all, and I'm still confused about what mode to set if I want to see the analysis result in sonar server instead of github.

Fig.1 : The whole server is empty. This server is actually working, and it has been commenting on github for couple weeks now. However, the server itself does not store any analysis at all - it just pipelines everything to github and then forgets it without storing anything in the database itself. The reason? Fig 2.

[image]

Fig.2 : This is the reason. Github plugin prevents the `sonar.analysis.mode` from ever being set as `publish`. Without `publish` mode, the server can never store results in itself. I can't just uninstall this because I need the github commenting feature.
Therefore, I need a separate project to store the whole analysis, but to do that I need to disable this plugin behavior for just that specific project...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved : I think leaving in github credentials in SonarScanner properties was the problem. After removing all the github related information in properties, it seems to be working.

Scroll down to bottom to read the conclusion.

Git integration working config:

```
sonar.projectKey=${componentName}
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.analysis.mode=issues
sonar.profile=My_Analysis_Profile
sonar.github.repository=${repository}
sonar.github.endpoint=https://customossendpoint/api/v3
sonar.github.login=someusername
sonar.github.oauth=somehashkey123
sonar.login=id
sonar.password=pass
sonar.github.pullRequest=${pr}
sonar.host.url=http://sonarserver:19000
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true 
sonar.github.disableInlineComments=false
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes
```

Tried to make it publish to server but analysis couldn't start due to "Doesn't support sonar.analysis.mode=publish" error message:

```
sonar.projectKey=${componentName}
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
sonar.profile=My_Analysis_Profile
sonar.github.repository=${repository}
sonar.github.endpoint=https://customossendpoint/api/v3
sonar.github.login=someusername
sonar.github.oauth=somehashkey123
sonar.login=id
sonar.password=pass
sonar.github.pullRequest=${pr}
sonar.host.url=http://sonarserver:19000
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true 
sonar.github.disableInlineComments=false
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes
```

Rolling back to "issues" mode because nobody knew what the mode's purpose even was, and tried to make it stop publishing to github by erasing github related options (it didn't send to github, but now it didn't send to server either):

```
sonar.projectKey=${componentName}
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.analysis.mode=issues
sonar.profile=My_Analysis_Profile
sonar.login=id
sonar.password=pass
sonar.host.url=http://sonarserver:19000
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=false
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes
```

Finally figured out the answer:

```
sonar.projectKey=${componentName}
sonar.projectName=${componentName}
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
sonar.profile=My_Analysis_Profile
sonar.login=id
sonar.password=pass
sonar.host.url=http://sonarserver:19000
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=false
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes
```

Conclusion: `sonar.analysis.mode` is very confusing. `issues` and `preview` seem to be almost identical; it doesn't store results in the server, and it's just a pipeline either by showing on console when running sonarrunner manually, or by pipelining it to sonarqube github plugin to post as a comment.
When sonarqube github plugin is active, it prohibits any mode other than `issues` and `preview`. In order to post it to the server, it needs to be set as `publish`. To do that, we need to make sure the github plugin isn't used. **We can "disable" the plugin project-wise simply by omitting any github related properties(ie. `sonar.github.login`).**